# ImageSearch doesn't work on second display

Tags: key, autohotkey, auto

ImageSearch works only on the primary laptop screen and doesn't work on the second monitor connected via DisplayPort and it's above(vertical).

Laptop's screen resolution: 1920x1080
2nd monitor's screen resoultion: 1920x1200

I've already trying SysGet but can't quite understand how it works and how to implement it to the code.

```
#SingleInstance Force
CoordMode, Pixel
Loop {
ImageSearch, ax, ay, 0, 0 , A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, MSGW.bmp
if ErrorLevel = 0
    MsgBox, %ax%, %ay% 
}
return
```

I also tried this with no effect:

```
#SingleInstance Force
CoordMode, Pixel

SysGet, VirtualScreenWidth, 78
SysGet, VirtualScreenHeight, 79

SysGet, VirtualScreenLeft, 76
SysGet, VirtualScreenTop, 77
Loop {
ImageSearch, ax, ay, VirtualScreenLeft, VirtualScreenTop, VirtualScreenLeft+VirtualScreenWidth, VirtualScreenTop+VirtualScreenHeight, MSGW.bmp
if ErrorLevel = 0
    MsgBox, %ax%, %ay% 
}
return
```

Please give me some hints how may I achieve this. I want this script to works on entire 2nd monitor.

Comment: run this script [getmouseposition.ahk](https://pastebin.com/btDKc66f), it will show you the mouse coordinates, movi it to the second monitor and check if you are using the coorect coordinates in your ImageSearch command.

Comment: I got past this issue by using modifiers in the image parameter.

Comment: I struggled mightily with this and ultimately realized that the display scaling on my laptop screen (125%) did not match the scaling on my external displays (100%). In this situation, it seems one must either match scaling across all displays or capture the target image on both displays and try them both.